# Print summary statistics in sub-groups of flextable object

Tags: r, flextable

**Context:** I am trying to create a docx table with summary statistics by groups.

**Question:** how to add summary statistics (e.g. `sum`) on top or bottom of each group and get a "total" line as last row?

So far I got good results using `flextable::as_grouped_data()` as shown here: https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/reference/as_grouped_data.html#see-also

**Example:**

```
library(dplyr) # feel free to use data.table if you prefer, I am just more used to dplyr
data_co2_2 <- CO2 %>% 
  group_by(Type, Treatment, conc) %>% 
  summarise(uptake = mean(uptake)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Type, values_from = uptake)

data_co2_2 <- as_grouped_data(x = data_co2_2, groups = c("Treatment"))
```

Output:

```
data_co2
#>     Treatment conc   Quebec Mississippi
#> 1  nonchilled   NA       NA          NA
#> 3        <NA>   95 15.26667    11.30000
#> 4        <NA>  175 30.03333    20.20000
#> 5        <NA>  250 37.40000    27.53333
#> 6        <NA>  350 40.36667    29.90000
#> 7        <NA>  500 39.60000    30.60000
#> 8        <NA>  675 41.50000    30.53333
#> 9        <NA> 1000 43.16667    31.60000
#> 2     chilled   NA       NA          NA
#> 10       <NA>   95 12.86667     9.60000
#> 11       <NA>  175 24.13333    14.76667
#> 12       <NA>  250 34.46667    16.10000
#> 13       <NA>  350 35.80000    16.60000
#> 14       <NA>  500 36.66667    16.63333
#> 15       <NA>  675 37.50000    18.26667
#> 16       <NA> 1000 40.83333    18.73333
```

**Expected output:** instead of `NA` in the "group" line I would like to display a summary statistic (like the sum of the sub-group). Icing on the cake: display a "Overall total" on the bottom of the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> instead of NA in the "group" line I would like to display a summary statistic (like the sum of the sub-group).

That's not possible if using `as_grouped_data() %>% as_flextable()`. The value displayed is the name of the group.

The following is a proposition:

```
library(flextable)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

CO2 <- CO2 %>% 
  mutate(conc = as.character(conc))

agg1 <- CO2 %>% 
  group_by(Type, Treatment, conc) %>% 
  summarise(uptake = mean(uptake), .groups = "drop") 

agg2 <- CO2 %>% 
  group_by(Type, Treatment) %>% 
  summarise(uptake = mean(uptake), .groups = "drop") %>% 
  mutate(conc="Overall")

agg3 <- CO2 %>% 
  group_by(Type) %>% 
  summarise(uptake = mean(uptake), .groups = "drop")  %>% 
  mutate(conc="Overall", Treatment = "Overall")


all_data <- bind_rows(agg1, agg2, agg3) %>% 
  arrange(Type, Treatment, conc) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Type, values_from = uptake)

as_grouped_data(x = all_data, groups = c("Treatment")) %>% 
  as_flextable() %>% 
  compose(i = ~ is.na(conc) & is.na(Treatment), 
          j = "conc", value = as_paragraph("avg for all conc")) %>% 
  compose(i = ~ is.na(conc) & is.na(Treatment), 
          j = "conc", value = as_paragraph("avg for all conc")) %>% 
  bold(bold = TRUE, i = ~!is.na(Treatment)) %>% 
  color(i= ~ conc %in% "Overall", color = "red") %>% 
  colformat_double(j = c("Quebec", "Mississippi"), digits = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Again many many thanks, your solution is close enouh to the desired output. Only limit though, in order to have "Overall" displayed at the bottom, it might be required to "manually" set factor level to make a custom arranging.

Comment: you are right about factors. If any issue, ring a bell here or on github issue.